# How to CACHE query/find results with PAGINATION CakePhp 2.x?

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, pagination

I use `Cache::read()`, `Cache::write()` in CakePhp to cache queries.

**How to update paginator params or CACHE whole paginator?**

It easy to cache query result but how to cache `$this->Paginator->params()` too?

**I've tried** to `Cache::write()` `$this->Paginator->params()` but how to modify `$this->Paginator->params()` after caching? When I do someting like:
...

```
$this->Paginator->params['paging'][$model] = $paginator_params;
```

...
I've got notice:

```
Indirect modification of overloaded element of CakeRequest has no effect
```

**Where and when I can rewrite PAGINATOR params/set cached params?**

Thanks.

Comment: `PagiantorHelper::params()` is a method, not a property, also it's just a getter. Why exactly do you want to cache parameters in the first place, what are you trying to achieve? Note that these parameters are part component settings, part query results.

Comment: I want to cache all my results from query with pagination. When I cache query, paginator doesn't work (in my view shows query result but not paginator) - because my query result if from the cached file, so paginator params are empty. I've tried cache query result and paginator params to one file, but I do not know how to update paginator params (all pages, number of pages, page prev, page next, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cache `$this->request->params['paging']` array.

And you have to add Paginator Helper to `$helpers` array. If you don't, beforeRender method of Paginator helper won't be invoked and paging links will be broken.

```
$page = !isset($this->request->named['page']) ? '1' : $this->request->named['page'];
$products = Cache::read('my_unique_cache_id_' . $page, 'query');  
$paging = Cache::read('my_unique_cache_id_paging_' . $page, 'query');

if ($products && $paging) {
    $this->set('products', $products);
    $this->request->params['paging'] = $paging;

}else{
    $products = $this->paginate('Product');
    Cache::write('my_unique_cache_id_paging_' . $page, $this->request->params['paging'], 'query');
    Cache::write('my_unique_cache_id_' . $page, $products, 'query');
    $this->set('products', $products);
}
```

Comment: Thank You for: `$this->request->params['paging'] = $paging;` - I prefer Cache::write 'products' and 'paging' to 1 file: 'my_unique_cache_id' instead 2 files (second for paging) and to generate 'cache_id' I use `$cache_id = 'products_'. http_build_query($this->request->params['named']);` ;)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's come here looking for a CakePHP 2.5+ version of this, the following should work well, using Cache::remember:

```
list($products, $this->request->params['paging']) = Cache::remember('somestring', function() {
    return [$this->paginate('Articles'), $this->request->params['paging']];
});
```

You'll have an array, $products, which you can set onto your view for rendering.

Comment: It's not enough to just cache the 'paging' key of the params array. I ran into some problems with the PaginatorHelper doing that, so I just cached the whole params array.