# Cache and pagination with CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-3.0

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673738/how-to-cache-query-find-results-with-pagination-cakephp-2-x) is how to cache results with pagination with CakePHP 2.x.

I have not tried it yet, but I believe that the same method is valid with CakePHP 3.x.

However, since CakePHP 3.x introduces several new features for using the cache (for example, the `find()` method takes the `cache` option), I wanted to know if there is a faster method.

I have seen book and APIs, but is not mentioned anything special in this regard.

One thing: [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#using-controller-paginate) is explained that

> By default the paginate() method will use the default model for a
>   controller. You can also pass the resulting query of a find method:

Maybe is this? I use the `find()` method with the `cache` option and then I pass the results to `paginate()`?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not avise towards caching queries, specially not the results of a pagination. But you idea is in theory right:

```
$aKeyThatEncodesQueryStringAndConditions = ...;
$this->paginate($this->Users->find()->cache($aKeyThatEncodesQueryStringAndConditions));
```

Comment: Thanks @José, what do you think about performance by using `find()` more "paginator"?

Meanwhile, I confirm that the method that worked with CakePHP 2.x (first link of my question) works (of course!) also with CakePHP 3.x.

Comment: What do you mean with using find more "paginator" ?

Comment: I'm sorry, error due to tiredness. I wanted to say: about performance by using the `find()` method and passing the resulting query to the `paginate()` method

Comment: It is exactly the same, if you don't pass the query yourself to paginate(), it will create it for you

Comment: Ok, before we have to do something like this:
`$this->paginate = ['limit' => 2];`
@José, is it right?

Comment: Ok, all seems to work. There's only one issue: the `paginate()` method doesn't read the `limit' option set by the `find()` method, so this must be set again (it seems a bug...).
Note: it's important, as it was for CakePHP 2.x, that the key to the cache contains the current page number

Comment: Oops, I don't think it's the same thing: in this way it seems it always performs a "count" query

Comment: It will always do a count query, not matter what. That is how it can know th number of pages

Comment: the count query is not needed with the ["old" method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23811126/1480263), which at this point remains the best in terms of performance

Comment: Use `$query->counter($counterMethodCallback)`